# Ошибка установки Visual C++ 2015-2022

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, драйвер

Возникает ошибка при установке пакета драйверов Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 
Эта ошибка начала возникать, после того как видимо я переустановил Windows. Уже множество игры требует этот пакет, но я не могу их установить. Как будто где-то потерялся инициатор запуска установки "визуалки".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

РЕШЕНИЕ ДАННОЙ ПРОБЛЕМЫ     : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/problems-installing-microsoft-visual-c-2015-2019/5d15dfca-fdf5-4582-a5bd-0a8f91aecb9d